# GraphQL redirect when resolver throws error

Tags: node.js, redirect, graphql, apollo-server

I'm using `graphql-server-express` to build a GraphQL server that consumes a REST API.

I'm in the situation that a REST call could return a 301 or 401 status code when the user isn't authenticated to access the resource. I'm using a cookie that is set on the client and forwarded to the REST API while resolving the GraphQL query.

Is it possible to send a 301 redirect to the client in response to a call to the GraphQL endpoint when such an error occurs?

I've tried something like `res.sendStatus(301) …` in `formatError` but this doesn't work well as `graphql-server-express` tries to set headers after this.

I've also tried to tried to short-circuit the `graphqlExpress` middleware with something like this:

```
export default graphqlExpress((req, res) => {
  res.sendStatus(301);
  return;
});
```

While the client receives the correct result, the server still prints errors (in this case `TypeError: Cannot read property 'formatError' of undefined` – most likely because the middleware receives empty options).

Is there a good way how to get this to work? Thanks!

Comment: Redirect to where? Redirect in GraphQL does not really make sense. What if the client sends a query with two root nodes, one succeeds (no need for login) and one fails, what do you send, 300 or 200?

Comment: If at least one field fails, a redirect should be sent in my case.

Comment: But graphql queries are executed by JS code, not by browser directly, jsut sending the redirect does not mean the browser will load the login page. Your graphql client, needs to detect this response code then be hardcoded to do something when it happens.

Comment: It's better just to send the same information in your "json error" response and have your client react to it. Changing the response code does not help you at all.

Comment: You're actually right. I somehow thought that the 301 status code will cause the client to change it's location, but e.g. `fetch` just follows the redirect and will load that resource. So probably the best way is like you mentioned throwing a custom redirect error in my resolver which a client knows how to handle – maybe with an [apollo client afterware](http://dev.apollodata.com/core/network.html#networkInterfaceAfterware) (in the linked example they're actually using the status code of the response to react to the logout)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how I implemented this.

On the server side:

```
// Setup
export default class UnauthorizedError extends Error {
  constructor({statusCode = 401, url}) {
    super('Unauthorized request to ' + url);
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
  }
}

// In a resolver
throw new UnauthorizedError({url});

// Setup of the request handler
graphqlExpress(async (req, res) => ({
  schema: ...,
  formatError(error) {
    if (error.originalError instanceof UnauthorizedError) {
      res.status(error.originalError.statusCode);
      res.set('Location', 'http://domain.tld/login');
    } else {
      res.status(500);
    }

    return error;
  },
});
```

On the client side:

```
const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface();

networkInterface.useAfter([{
  applyAfterware({response}, next) {
    if ([401, 403].includes(response.status)) {
      document.location = response.headers.get('Location');
    } else {
      next();
    }
  }
}]);
```

---

In Apollo Client 2.0, you can probably use [apollo-link-error](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/master/Upgrade.md#afterware-error) on the client side for this.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of handling redirects in graphql resolvers is by setting "status" as 302 (http status code for redirect) and  "Location" in the response like below code,

```
this.Query = {
  downloadFile: (parent, { url }, { res }) => {
    res.status(302);
    res.set('Location', url);

    return;
}
```